# Getting Error when reading a file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm getting a simple but confusing error when trying to create a login worker
via python.

Here's the error i'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stratixlogin.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "stratixlogin.py", line 78, in main
    login_worker()
  File "stratixlogin.py", line 51, in login_worker
    data = f.read()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose datanter code
```

Here is where the Error is occuring:

```
with open("global_users.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = f.read()
        if data == username_ask:
            print(G+"Success!")

            password_ask = raw_input(O+"Password:"+W+" ")

            with open("global_passwords.txt", "r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    data = f.read()
                    if data == password_ask:
                        print(G+"Success!")

                    else:
                        print(R+"Incorrect Password!")

        else:
            print(R+"No Users Found!")
```

I am not sure what the error is here, But i am confused on how to fix this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix iterating through the lines of the file (the `for` loop) and `read()`.
This is enough:

```
with open("global_users.txt", "r") as f:
    for data in f:
        if data == username_ask:
            print(G+"Success!")

            password_ask = raw_input(O+"Password:"+W+" ")

            with open("global_passwords.txt", "r") as f:
                for line in f:
                    data = f.read()
                    if data == password_ask:
                        print(G+"Success!")

                    else:
                        print(R+"Incorrect Password!")

        else:
            print(R+"No Users Found!")
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I now just have to fix my new occuring error:) Thanks for the help man!